# Parse Shellcheck output in Eclipse problems view

Tags: eclipse, bash, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle, shellcheck

I'm working on a mixed language integration project involving copious amounts of Bash. We use Eclipse as our IDE due to its tight integration with our SCM (not Git).

I have successfully configured a builder to run shellcheck against bash code and the output goes to the console view on run. Shellcheck can output in a variety of styles including checkstyle xml, and gcc but I'd like Eclipse to suck that output back in and do clever stuff with it - highlighting problem lines, allowing me to click on the error and jump to the relevant line etc.

I can't find a shellcheck plugin for Eclipse, but I'm wondering whether it is possible to integrate shellcheck with Eclipse via an intermediate plugin which leverages shellchecks ability to output gcc or checkstyle format messages. Has anyone come across a plugin which can do this?

I've come across terms such as markers etc but I don't have the experience to start writing an Eclipse plugin of my own (unless someone can point me to a comprehensive, well commented, sample plugin)...

Comment: The problems view is meant to show markers (API `IMarker`) which indicate a problem whin a workspace resource (API `IResource`). As far as I understand, you intend to create markers from parsing console output. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: I'm using a program called ShellCheck to validate my bash scripts. This outputs fine to the console and I can of course read through this and modify my code appropriately. There is no tight integration for Eclipse that I can find, but ShellCheck can output in a variety of text formats including gcc and checkstyle. If I had time to learn how to write a plug-in which could parse this output myself, I would but I'm wondering whether there is a plug-in already out there that can go some way to helping me do this.